# two non-degenerate quadratic forms on $GF(2)^2r$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

I know this:

There are two non-degenerate quadratic forms on $GF(2)^2r$. The hyperbolic form may be taken to be
$Q^+(x)=x_0 x_1 + \cdots +x_{2r-2}x_{2r-1}$ ,

and the elliptic form to be

$Q^-(x)=x^2_0 +x_0x_1 +x^2_1 +x_2x_3 + \cdots +x_{2r-2}x_{2r-1}$.

and my question is:

I want to know more about this, do you know any book or article about this?

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Meanwhile, see http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-67

Comment: thank you. it helps me very much.

Comment: For the curious, see well-informed answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115573/two-non-degenerate-quadratic-forms-on-gf22r